# Load More when reaching the end of a UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am trying to implement a load more function within a table view. I read the that code would go inside of the `cellForRowAt` func, but this is not working.

I have two UITableViews in this specific ViewController. Everything is working great until this.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if (tableView == userSearchesTableView) {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? CellBasicItemInfo {
            cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            let responseItems = userRecentSearches[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureCell(item: responseItems)
            cell.setNeedsLayout()
            return cell
        } else {
            return CellBasicItemInfo()
        }
        

    } else {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "itemCell", for: indexPath) as? CellItems {
            cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            let responseItems = resultsModelArray[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureCell(item: responseItems)
            cell.setNeedsLayout()

            if (indexPath.row == self.resultsModelArray.count) {
                print("REACHED THE BOTTOM") // does not print
            }

            return cell
        } else {
            return CellItems()
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

Is there another or better way to handle this functionality?

per comment (did not work)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (tableView == userSearchesTableView) {
        if (indexPath.row == self.userRecentSearches.count) {
            print("REACHED THE BOTTOM RECENT")
        }
    } 
}
```

UPDATE

adding the follow worked for me.

```
...
if (indexPath.row == self.userRecentSearches.count - 2) {
    print("REACHED THE BOTTOM RECENT")
}
...
```

Comment: I don't really understand the question, do you want to lazy load the tableView, or do you want to differentiate between two table views handlers?

Comment: sorry for the confusion @AvivFrenkel. I have two tableviews, thats why my function looks that way. I want to "lazy load" the "itemCell". When I reach the bottom of it, I will call a function to load load items in.

Comment: Ok so what you need to do is implement the tableViewDelegate "willDisplay cell at", and in it check if you are on the last or second to last cell, if you are then call the API call which gives you more data from your servers and update the tableView data

Comment: see my comment above, that did not work for me. @AvivFrenkel

Comment: thanks @AvivFrenkel, i figured it out. thanks so much. if you want to post it as an answer, i will accept it.

Comment: i'll update an answer later today thanks